# Umbraco says it's saved changes to templates but the changes are lost

Tags: umbraco

Each time I make a change to an Umbraco template and press Save, I get the confirmation popup saying:

> Template saved
>   Template saved without any errors!

However, when I return to that template (click on another template and then back again), the changes have been lost.

I've ensured that the user account running my IIS application pool has Full Control over the \Views folder containing the .cshtml files (i.e. the Umbraco templates).

Strangely this just started happening, after it had been letting me make template changes with no problems. I can manually edit the .cshtml files on disk, but this seems ridiculous.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'll provide an answer for others' future reference (although the reasons are unclear to me). It appears the change I was making to my Template must've been deemed invalid by Umbraco - when I strip the template text down to just a single, empty div and save it, the change is persisted successfully.

The confusing thing is that Umbraco provides no feedback as to why it's not saving - in fact it tells you that it HAS saved successfully.

Bizarre and confusing.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1) Have you checked that the following Windows accounts have full permissions for all folders "IUSR", "IIS_IUSRS", "NETWORK SERVICE" ?

2) Probably not but I have had problems in the past with caching. Have you disabled (set from True to False) caching properties in /config/umbracoSettings.config ?  This should always be done during development.

Comment: These are good suggestions and I did check those things. The answer was in fact that my template changes were invalid because of the Razor syntax I was using.

Answer (score 0):

Just been editing my templates and got this problem. Fixed it by doing the following:

- sign out of umbraco
- clear your browsing data
- sign back into umbraco

always be sure to copy and paste your code somewhere to keep it safe, and it can be easily pasted back in. Seems like a bug to me... but it saved after I did that.

(Using Umbraco 7)